# putting colon (:) in xml attribute

Tags: java, android, xml, attributes, xmlserializer

I am working on android project and in some portion of task I need to create xml document file.
I need to create attribute containing colon like this

```
<APPLICAD_EXPORT xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///c:/temp/applicad-export.xsd">
```

I can create xml file sucessfully, but the problem is that I cannot add colon for the attribute APPLICAD_EXPORT.

so far I did like this for getting colon for attribute prefix

```
XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();

            //we set the FileOutputStream as output for the serializer, using UTF-8 encoding
            serializer.setOutput(fileos, "UTF-8");
            //Write <?xml declaration with encoding (if encoding not null) and standalone flag (if standalone not null)
            serializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.valueOf(true));
            //set indentation option
            serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);

            serializer.startTag(null, "APPLICAD_EXPORT");
            serializer.attribute(null, "xsi&#58;noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "file:///c:/temp/applicad-export.xsd");
```

but it shows error saying **Specification mandate value for attribute xsi**

I guess there may be some way to achieve this but I couldn't figured it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The colon is special: your attribute name consists of a namespace prefix (which is a shorthand for the namespace URI, in this case "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance") and a local name, separated by a colon.

Your call to `XmlSerializer.attribute()` should specify the namespace URI as the first argument, and the local name (`"noNamespaceSchemaLocation"`) as the second.

You also need to bind the namespace prefix to the URI using `XmlSerializer.setPrefix("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")`.

Comment: I tried like this 

serializer.setPrefix("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            serializer.startTag(null, "APPLICAD_EXPORT");
            serializer.attribute(null, "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "file:///c:/temp/applicad-export.xsd");

but didnt get the required result rather I got this

<APPLICAD_EXPORT xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///c:/temp/applicad-export.xsd">

but required is <APPLICAD_EXPORT xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///c:/temp/applicad-export.xsd">

Comment: Well, read my answer again. The first argument to attribute() should not be null.

Comment: thank you sir I have tried some think like this and m near to my result
 serializer.setPrefix("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            serializer.startTag(null, "APPLICAD_EXPORT");
            serializer.attribute("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "file:///c:/temp/applicad-export.xsd");